# Scroll with arrow keys on dropdown - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building an autocomplete component in vuejs.

And at the moment I got stuck in the scroll animation.

The purpose is to click on the arrow keys to scroll as the direction of the key, but the scroll is only executed when the option is not visible.

I wanted something of this kind, but in vue / javascript. - http://jsfiddle.net/kMzR9/3/

If you can not see the problem in the example I left here since the screen is small, here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/v7yd94r5/

Here is an example of what I have.

```js
const Autocomplete = {
  name: "autocomplete",
  template: "#autocomplete",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => []
    },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: "",
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      // Let's warn the parent that a change was made
      this.$emit("input", this.search);

      // Is the data given by an outside ajax request?
      if (this.isAsync) {
        this.isLoading = true;
      } else {
        // Let's search our flat array
        this.filterResults();
        this.isOpen = true;
      }
    },

    filterResults() {
      // first uncapitalize all the things
      this.results = this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    },
    setResult(result) {
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    onArrowDown(evt) {
      if (this.arrowCounter < this.results.length) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter + 1;
      }
    },
    onArrowUp() {
      if (this.arrowCounter > 0) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter - 1;
      }
    },
    onEnter() {
      this.search = this.results[this.arrowCounter];
      this.isOpen = false;
      this.arrowCounter = -1;
    },
    showAll() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
   (this.isOpen) ? this.results = this.items : this.results = [];
    },
    handleClickOutside(evt) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(evt.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.arrowCounter = -1;
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    items: function(val, oldValue) {
      // actually compare them
      if (val.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = val;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "app",
  components: {
    autocomplete: Autocomplete
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
    font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #2c3e50;
}

.autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
}

.autocomplete-results {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-result {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-result.is-active,
.autocomplete-result:hover {
    background-color: #4aae9b;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <autocomplete :items="[ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Tangerine', 'Pineapple']" />

</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="autocomplete">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @input="onChange" v-model="search" @keyup.down="onArrowDown" @keyup.up="onArrowUp" @keyup.enter="onEnter" @click="showAll" />
    <ul id="autocomplete-results" v-show="isOpen" class="autocomplete-results">
      <li class="loading" v-if="isLoading">
        Loading results...
      </li>
      <li v-else v-for="(result, i) in results" :key="i" @click="setResult(result)" class="autocomplete-result" :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }">
        {{ result }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The purpose is to click on the down / up arrow if the option is not visible to scroll to this option, at this time does not happen, always remain the first 3 options visible while the one that is active does not appear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v7yd94r5/1/ - As the screen is small, it may not be able to see the problem, so I'll leave it here jsfiddle. I have already updated the issue with this link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a function to check the position of the current element and move the scroll container if needed, there's also a problem with the arrowDown function:

```
<ul ... ref="scrollContainer" ... >
    ...
    <li ref="options" ... >
    ...
</ul>

onArrowDown(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    if (this.arrowCounter < this.results.length-1) { <--- HERE NEED -1
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter + 1;
        this.fixScrolling();
    }
},
onArrowUp(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    if (this.arrowCounter > 0) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter - 1;
        this.fixScrolling()
    }
},
fixScrolling(){
    const liH = this.$refs.options[this.arrowCounter].clientHeight;
    this.$refs.scrollContainer.scrollTop = liH * this.arrowCounter;
},
```

```js
const Autocomplete = {
  name: "autocomplete",
  template: "#autocomplete",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => Array(150).fill().map((_, i) => `Fruit ${i+1}`)
    },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: "",
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      // Let's warn the parent that a change was made
      this.$emit("input", this.search);

      // Is the data given by an outside ajax request?
      if (this.isAsync) {
        this.isLoading = true;
      } else {
        // Let's search our flat array
        this.filterResults();
        this.isOpen = true;
      }
    },

    filterResults() {
      // first uncapitalize all the things
      this.results = this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    },
    setResult(result, i) {
      this.arrowCounter = i;
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    onArrowDown(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault()
      if (this.arrowCounter < this.results.length-1) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter + 1;
        this.fixScrolling();
      }
    },
    onArrowUp(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault()
      if (this.arrowCounter > 0) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter - 1;
        this.fixScrolling()
      }
    },
    fixScrolling(){
      const liH = this.$refs.options[this.arrowCounter].clientHeight;
      this.$refs.scrollContainer.scrollTop = liH * this.arrowCounter;
    },
    onEnter() {
      this.search = this.results[this.arrowCounter];
      this.isOpen = false;
      this.arrowCounter = -1;
    },
    showAll() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
   (this.isOpen) ? this.results = this.items : this.results = [];
    },
    handleClickOutside(evt) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(evt.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.arrowCounter = -1;
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    items: function(val, oldValue) {
      // actually compare them
      if (val.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = val;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "app",
  components: {
    autocomplete: Autocomplete
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
}

.autocomplete-results {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-result {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-result.is-active,
.autocomplete-result:hover {
  background-color: #4aae9b;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <autocomplete />

</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="autocomplete">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @input="onChange" v-model="search" @keyup.down="onArrowDown" @keyup.up="onArrowUp" @keyup.enter="onEnter" @click="showAll" />
    <ul id="autocomplete-results" v-show="isOpen" ref="scrollContainer" class="autocomplete-results">
      <li class="loading" v-if="isLoading">
        Loading results...
      </li>
      <li ref="options" v-else v-for="(result, i) in results" :key="i" @click="setResult(result, i)" class="autocomplete-result" :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }">
        {{ result }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: One question, when there are many options in the array happens this bug, in which the scroll is faster than the position where it goes. - https://jsfiddle.net/v7yd94r5/5/, and I can not figure out why.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.... changed a little bit my solution to fix that problem. Also fixed a problem with the onClick event, you need to set this.arrowCounter, check the snippet to see the changes.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I know it may be old but you could scroll using [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
fixScrolling() {
    currentElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' });
},
```

Comment: Much better! I took some inspiration also from this Pull Request on Vue Bootstrap Typeahead: https://github.com/alexurquhart/vue-bootstrap-typeahead/pull/44/files

Comment: Great answer! Thank you